# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to login as Administrator. I used Multiple authentication one for my **User** that works fine and second for **Admin** that I'm trying to login but when I insert right values in my database which I manually inserted the values using **Seeding** it gives me a error which I don't know the cause.

[image: Error]

What I did is I configure my **auth.php** So I can have two authentications for User and Admin.

```
<?php

return [



'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],



'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins'
    ]
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

     // For admin
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class
    ]

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],



'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

**create_admins_table** - Migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
}
```

My migration files are set. So I migrated it.

**Admin** - Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Admin extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
use Authenticatable;


protected $guard = "admins";

protected $table = 'admins';

protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token'
];
}
```

**AdminTableSeeder** - Seeds

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    DB::table('admins')->delete();

    $admins = array(
    array('username' => 'admin',
          'password' => Hash::make('admin'))
    );

    DB::table('admins')->insert($admins);
}
}
```

**AdminController** - Controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
public function postAdminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, 
    [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:7',
    ]);

    if(!Auth::attempt($request->only(['username','password']), $request->has('remember')))
    {
        dd('error');
    }

    dd('Succesful!');
}
}
```

**UPDATE!!**

So I changed my username and password to `letmein` to avoid my confusion. I attempt to login the right values but I can't still login. `!Auth:attempt` won't match my values in my database and prints me a "error" message.

```
public function postAdminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, 
    [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:7',
    ]);

    if(!Auth::attempt($request->only(['username','password']), $request->has('remember')))
    {
        dd('error');
    }

    dd('Succesful!');
}
```

**admin.blade.php**

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('auth.admin') }}">

            <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'has-errors' : '' }}">
                <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control">

                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                    <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-errors' : '' }}">
                <label for = "password" class = "control-label">Password</label>
                <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control">

                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                @endif

            </div>

            <div class = "checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type = "checkbox" name = "remember">Remember me</input>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </div>

            <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

        </form>
```

Comment: Your seeder references an `admin` table whereas everything else references `admins`.

Comment: @Mei I didn't notice that. Already updated. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Mei Your observation seem quite sound... and (Francisunoxx) did you say you updated it here in this post or within your own code back there?

Comment: @Poiz I updated the same. But still getting the error. Any help bro?

Comment: The original SQL does not contain a `WHERE username = 'admin'` so check that the field in the HTML has the correct name attribute. Instead of `dd('error')` try dd($request->only(['username', 'password']).

Comment: @Mei I think I didn't miss anything in my html field. Check my updated post. So inside my `if condition` I will insert this `dd($request->only(['username', 'password'])`?

Comment: You should try that. And read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: @Mei I tried your code but it say's `syntax error, unexpected ';'`?

Comment: You need to check your syntax then. The error message should tell you which line to check. My suggestion did not contain a semi-colon.

Comment: @Mei It prints me the value of my `username` and `password`? But still not accepting the value given.

Comment: Then have you checked that the username/password are correct? you could try `Auth::attempt` with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0):

Your Table name is in Question here... We think it should have been "admins" in the AdminTableSeeder like so:

```
        use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

        class AdminTableSeeder extends Seeder {

            public function run() {
                DB::table('admins')->delete();  //<== "admins" AS DEFINED IN YOUR CONFIG::: NOT "admin"

                $admin = array(
                array('username' => 'admin',       
                      'password' => Hash::make('admin'))
                );

                DB::table('admins')->insert($admin);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Already did that bro. I get a new error. It won't authenticate me. I already multiple authentication in my config. Why still I can't log in?

Answer (score 0):

AdminTableSeeder - Seeds

Use truncate instead of delete

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
  DB::table('admins')->truncate();

  $admins = array(
  array('username' => 'admin',
        'password' => Hash::make('admin'))
  );

  DB::table('admins')->insert($admins);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

The SQL query next to the error message says

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `admin` where `password`=admin
```

Now, in your WHERE clause password is backticked, so I assume it is a column(not a table). Backticks are usually used in SQL for table names or column names. But the you compare the column name to admin, without ticks. 'admin' is not a reserved word, and it is not quoted in your query as a text string should be, so the database server then starts looking for a table with that name to match.

So, have you tried adding quotes there?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate FROM `admin` WHERE `password`='admin'
```

Edit:

If all else fails you might also want to simply dump the database queries being issued. Add a listener/dump:

```
\DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bindings);
    var_dump($time);
});
```

..and check the output.

Comment: The admin for username and password. Is the value that I seed in my database. So I didn't use any Select statement here.

Comment: @Francisunoxx The top box in your message (QueryException) contains the SQL query I quoted above. So yes, it is a Select statement, but it is probably issued behind the scenes by Laravel. Can you use the call stack to see from where Connection.php:680 is called? Could it be the $this->validate() and unique:admin?

Comment: Where I'm gonna insert this `DB:listen`?

Comment: As late as possible, right before your code that you want to debug, to have as few "extraneous" printouts as possible?

Comment: Can you provide examples? I didn't get exactly what your saying bro.